# iOS code signing key 'Apple Distribution: xx' not found in keychain in appcenter

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, appcenter

I am currently trying to assist building a iOS app in appcenter.ms which has different branches set with their own builds.

Each branch has their own project bundle identifier and we are struggling a little with less or no documentation on how this was originally setup by a previous developer.

What we have now on the branch build configuration in appcenter is:

- Project: xxx.sln
- Configuration: Release Prod
- SDK version: Xamarin.iOS 15.4
- Xcode version 13.2.1
- Build scripts: none
- Build type: Device build
- Build frequency: Manually choose when to run builds
- Environment variables: none
- Sign builds: xx.mobileprovision & distribution.p12 cert

When we run the build we get the following error:

```
"/Users/runner/work/1/s/WAppShell.sln" (Rebuild target) (1) ->
"/Users/runner/work/1/s/WAppShell/WAppShell.iOS/WAppShell.iOS.csproj" (Rebuild target) (3) ->
(_DetectSigningIdentity target) -> 
  /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(1566,3): error : iOS code signing key 'Apple Distribution: XXX, Inc (xxxxxxxxxx)' not found in keychain. [/Users/runner/work/1/s/WAppShell/WAppShell.iOS/WAppShell.iOS.csproj]
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(1566,3): error :          [/Users/runner/work/1/s/WAppShell/WAppShell.iOS/WAppShell.iOS.csproj]

    5 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:01:31.79
##[error]Xamarin.iOS task failed with error Error: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6_12_12/bin/msbuild failed with return code: 1. For guidance on setting up the build definition, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=760847.
##[section]Finishing: Build Xamarin.iOS solution
```

Based on the guidance provided by Microsoft I should mention that if I navigate to the dev ops project > pipelines, we do not have any pipelines set up.

And if I go even further up the build pipeline logs I will see that for both the **Install Apple certificate** and **Install Apple provisioning profile** tasks will complete without any errors.

So I am a bit uncertain what is going on here, since I am kind of a middle-man just attempting to get this build running and no previous experience with this.

Comment: Usually an efficient way to diagnose build failures is comparing them to a working build. If building works locally but not in App Center, this problem is usually because of uncommitted files, different tooling, or unrestored dependencies.you can check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/troubleshooting/build-failed to get more info